# How to parse an 80-bit floating point number in Crystal?

Tags: floating-point, crystal-lang

I want to read an [80-bit floating point number (according to the IEEE 754 standard)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) from an `IO` object and store it in a usable type like `BigDecimal`, `Float64` or something similar. (After reading the number, I don't need to keep the full precision. That's why I'm also fine with a `Float64`.)

Right now, I'm calculating the number myself. Is there any built-in way of doing this with Crystal's standard library?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the number represented in the IO? Binary or decimal?

Comment: It is represented in binary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Appears you'd have to write your own, here's an example: https://github.com/brianmhunt/float80/blob/master/src/float80.js (I think BigNumber equiv. is BigDecimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal's standard library has no built-in support for reading 80bit or arbitrary width binary representations of floating point numbers. Only the languages's primitive types (Float32 and Float64) are supported out of the box (see [IO::ByteFormat](https://crystal-lang.org/api/IO/ByteFormat.html)).